# Use value inside an [Object Promise]

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm having a issue trying to use a value that I get doing a call to an API.

Here is my Typescript code:

```
 private async getPersonName() {
            let fullName = await Api.GetName('Data($select=FullName)', `PersonId  eq ${currentPersonId}`);
            return fullName.value[0].Data.FullName;
        }
```

And then, I need to just append it to the DOM using Jquery.

```
$("#myId").text(/*getPersonName() value*/);
```

When I try to append this it show **[object Promise]** in the DOM. I'm not really sure how to properly use this value.

Regards.

Comment: Looks like your `Api.GetName` function returns a promise Object

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. Maybe Promise.Resolve can be used here?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (or [this blog post](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261)) so you understand the concept and then it should be easy to solve ;)

Comment: Alright. Thank you @Capricorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `$("#myId").text(await getPersonName());`

Or this:

```
private async getPersonName() {
   let fullName = await Api.GetName('Data($select=FullName)', `PersonId  eq ${currentPersonId}`);
   return fullName.value[0].Data.FullName;
}
```

...

```
getPersonName().then((value) => {
    $("#myId").text(value);
})
```

Comment: Did you change something in the `private async getPersonName()`?

Comment: @Bergi, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Since `getPersonName()` is declared `async`, you should probably `await` the call to it.

```
var value = await getPersonName();
$("#myId").text(value);
```

or even

```
$("#myId").text(await getPersonName());
```